# VSC Run and Debug - Process exited with code 1 - But runs fine in terminal

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I am trying to test this serverless application but the `Run and Debug` function in VSC does not want to run it. I've tried numerous amount of pathing to the node modules but this does not change the outcome.

My configuration:

```
        {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "invoke local",
        "program": "/Users/MYNAME/.nvm/versions/node/v17.8.0/lib/node_modules/serverless/bin/serverless",
        "args": [
            "invoke",
            "local",
            "-f",
            "${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "-p",
            "testEvents/${fileBasenameNoExtension}.json"
        ],
        "cwd": "${fileDirname}/../",
        "skipFiles": [
            "<node_internals>/**/*.js",
            "node_modules/**"
        ],
        "env": { "AWS_PROFILE": "awsProfile" },
        "outFiles": [
            "${workspaceRoot}/**/*.js"
        ]
    },
```

runs:

```
/Users/MYNAME/.nvm/versions/node/v17.8.0/bin/node ./../../../../../.nvm/versions/node/v17.8.0/lib/node_modules/serverless/bin/serverless invoke local -f fileName -p testEvents/FileName.json
```

which results in `Process exited with code 1`

When the same line is run terminal it returns the desired result.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Problem solved by running `"console": "externalTerminal"` in the config, this terminal gave me a more detailed error & in my case it was solved by fixed a typo in my AWS profile.

Still strange that it did run the line in the terminal as mentioned before, I've some could explain that, would be great.